# Is there any difference between import order plugin using eslint or prettier?

Tags: import, eslint, prettier

My repository has eslint and prettier both...

I'm considering using import order plugin.

There are plugins that order imports on prettier, and eslint both.

Is there any difference or performance diff between those?

Prettier Plugin was https://github.com/trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports
Eslint Plugin was https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import

I found that there are lots of things that can be handle on Eslint-plugin-import but I will use only import order function.